# PDO prepared Statements correct?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to use some PDO prepared statements for the first time to prevent a SQL Injection. I am quite new to SQL so the prepared statements are very bewildering to me. Do you think my SQL code with prepared statements is correct?

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {

    $suche = htmlspecialchars($_POST['suche']);

    $stmt->bindParam(':suche', $suche);

    if (!empty($suche)) {    

    $sql = new rex_sql;

    $sql->debugsql = 0;

    $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM rex_downloads WHERE dateiname LIKE '%:suche%' OR projektnummer LIKE '%:suche%' OR teilnehmer LIKE '%:suche%'");

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($sql->getRows() >= 1) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= $sql->getRows(); $i++, $sql->next())
    {
        $dateiname_suche = $sql->getValue("dateiname");
        $datei_projektnummer_suche = $sql->getValue("projektnummer");
        $teilnehmer_suche = $sql->getValue("teilnehmer");
        $dateidatum_suche = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($sql->getValue("dateidatum")));
        $dateizeit_suche = date("H.i",strtotime($sql->getValue("dateidatum")));
        $datei_projektseite_suche = $sql->getValue("projektseite");

        $suche_download_ausgabe .= '<li><a href="index.php?article_id='.$datei_projektseite_suche.'"></a><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>'.$dateiname_suche.'<ul><li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.$dateidatum_suche.' um '.$dateizeit_suche.' Uhr</li><li><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>'.$datei_projektnummer_suche.'</li><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.$teilnehmer_suche.'</li></ul></li>';   

    }  
    }   
    }   
    }        
    ?>
```

This is my "old" SQL Code (without prepared statements):

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {

    $suche = htmlspecialchars($_POST['suche']);

    if (!empty($suche)) {    

    $sql = new rex_sql;

    $sql->debugsql = 0;

    $sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM rex_downloads WHERE dateiname LIKE '%$suche%' OR projektnummer LIKE '%$suche%' OR teilnehmer LIKE '%$suche%'");

    if ($sql->getRows() >= 1) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= $sql->getRows(); $i++, $sql->next())
    {
        $dateiname_suche = $sql->getValue("dateiname");
        $datei_projektnummer_suche = $sql->getValue("projektnummer");
        $teilnehmer_suche = $sql->getValue("teilnehmer");
        $dateidatum_suche = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($sql->getValue("dateidatum")));
        $dateizeit_suche = date("H.i",strtotime($sql->getValue("dateidatum")));
        $datei_projektseite_suche = $sql->getValue("projektseite");

        $suche_download_ausgabe .= '<li><a href="index.php?article_id='.$datei_projektseite_suche.'"></a><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>'.$dateiname_suche.'<ul><li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.$dateidatum_suche.' um '.$dateizeit_suche.' Uhr</li><li><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>'.$datei_projektnummer_suche.'</li><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.$teilnehmer_suche.'</li></ul></li>';   

    }  
    }   
    }   
    }        
    ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you go to *CodeReview* as this site is about programming issues where the community provides solutions for issues. *CodeReview* suggests improvement to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your placeholders shouldn't be quoted. That makes it a literal string, not a placeholder. I also don't know what `getRows()` and `getValue` are. Try this out..

```
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {
    $suche = '%' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['suche']) . '%';
    $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM rex_downloads WHERE dateiname LIKE ? OR projektnummer LIKE ? OR teilnehmer LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($suche, $suche, $suche));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $suche_download_ausgabe = '';
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $dateiname_suche = $row['dateiname'];
            $datei_projektnummer_suche = $row['projektnummer'];
            $teilnehmer_suche = $row['teilnehmer'];
            $dateidatum_suche = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($row['dateidatum']));
            $dateizeit_suche = date("H.i",strtotime($row['dateidatum']));
            $datei_projektseite_suche = $row['projektseite'];
            $suche_download_ausgabe .= '<li><a href="index.php?article_id='.$datei_projektseite_suche.'"></a><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>'.$dateiname_suche.'<ul><li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.$dateidatum_suche.' um '.$dateizeit_suche.' Uhr</li><li><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>'.$datei_projektnummer_suche.'</li><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.$teilnehmer_suche.'</li></ul></li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No results';
    }
}
```

The `?`s are placeholders where the user values will be inserted. The `rowCount` is a PDO function to see how many rows the query returned. The `fetch` is another PDO function to pull the rows. There are references and write ups of these functions on the PHP site.

I'm also not sure you should be running `htmlspecialchars` on the user input. Was the data in the DB converted that way when inserted?

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I am using the "htmlspecialchars" because otherwise the user can input some HTML in the text-input and destroy the site :/

Comment: You aren't outputting `$suche` anywhere on the site though, you are only using that to query the database. In the db are the values converted to entities or are they the character. Also with `htmlspecialchars` you also should encode single quotes.